# https://login.microsoftonline.com & jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I need to perform the login on https://login.microsoftonline.com with jQuery.

Here is what I do:

1. Inject jQuery

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'
```

2. Set User Id

```
$("input#i0116").val("aa@my.company").change()
```

3. Click 'Next'

```
$("input#idSIButton9")[0].click()
```

But then I get the error:

> Enter a valid email address, phone number, or Skype name.

[image]

How to fix my JavaScript, because when I do that "manually", I don't get the error and the 'next' page is rendered?

Comment: They probably have code stopping you from programmatically entering the login information because it's against their terms of service...

Comment: Yeah don't do that. Just pop out the Microsoft login form and let the user do the actual logging in business.

Comment: This step is part of an automated Test (running under CodedUI).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found:

1. Inject jQuery

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'
```

2. Set User Id

```
$("input#i0116").val("aa@my.company")
```

3. **NEW:** Blur User Id

```
$("input#i0116").blur()
```

4. Click 'Next'

```
$("input#idSIButton9")[0].click()
```

> Warning: this is working **only** if the JavaScript is "injected" **via CodedUI** (otherwise, we still face the "focus" problems).